# Unable to execute stored Procedure using Java and JDBC on SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have been trying to execute a MS SQL Server stored procedure via JDBC today and have been unsuccessful thus far.  The stored procedure has 1 input and 1 output parameter.  With every combination I use when setting up the stored procedure call in code I get an error stating that the stored procedure couldn't be found.  I have provided the stored procedure I'm executing below (NOTE:  this is vendor code, so I cannot change it).

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROC [dbo].[spWCoTaskIdGen] 
@OutIdentifier int OUTPUT
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @HoldPolicyId int
DECLARE @PolicyId char(14)

IF NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM UniqueIdentifierGen (UPDLOCK)
)
INSERT INTO UniqueIdentifierGen VALUES (0)

UPDATE UniqueIdentifierGen 
SET 
    CurIdentifier = CurIdentifier + 1

SELECT @OutIdentifier = 
    (SELECT CurIdentifier
    FROM UniqueIdentifierGen)
END
```

The code looks like:

```
 CallableStatement statement = connection
            .prepareCall("{call dbo.spWCoTaskIdGen(?)}");
    statement.setInt(1, 0);
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

I get the following error:  SEVERE: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.spWCoTaskIdGen'.

I have also tried

```
    CallableStatement statement = connection
            .prepareCall("{? = call dbo.spWCoTaskIdGen(?)}");
    statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    statement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    statement.executeQuery();
```

The above results in:  SEVERE: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.spWCoTaskIdGen'.

I have also tried:

```
    CallableStatement statement = connection
            .prepareCall("{? = call spWCoTaskIdGen(?)}");
    statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    statement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    statement.executeQuery();
```

The code above resulted in the following error:  Could not find stored procedure 'spWCoTaskIdGen'.

Finally, I should also point out the following:

1. I have used the MS SQL Server Management Studio tool and have been able to successfully run the stored procedure.  The sql generated to execute the stored procedure is provided below:

   ```
   GO
   DECLARE @return_value int;
   DECLARE @OutIdentifier int;
   EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[spWCoTaskIdGen] @OutIdentifier = @OutIdentifier OUTPUT;
   SELECT
       @OutIdentifier [@OutIdentifier],
       @return_value [Return Value];
   GO
   ```
2. The code being executed runs with the same user id that was used in point #1 above.
3. In the code that creates the Connection object I log which database I'm connecting to and the code is connecting to the correct database.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have added an additional scenario:

    CallableStatement statement = 
       connection.prepareCall("{? = call spWCoTaskIdGen(?)}");
    statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    statement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    statement.executeQuery();

The code above resulted in the following error:

07:50:25,978 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Could not find stored procedure 'spWCoTaskIdGen'.

Comment: That didn't work out so well :)  I'll add the example to the original question above.

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using? JTDS?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely one of...

1. The credentials uses have no rights to run the code. You'd need a [`GRANT EXECUTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371(SQL.90).aspx) in the script above
2. Wrong database. For example, the stored proc was created in master but you are connected to "MyDB"

Comment: I have confirmed that the user does have grant privileges and that I am connected to the correct database.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Since it can't even find the procedure, I would first look to make sure that your user has execute privileges for that procedure.  You could try executing the proc with the same user from a tool like Squirrel.

Comment: I have done this and have provided the resulting SQL in the original question.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Squirrel will connect through JDBC, so if you try to run it through that you could verify that the driver/JDBC connection string isn't a problem.  You can download it from here: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you can't execute through Squirrel, it's probably more than likely your connection string rather than the driver.  Make sure it looks like jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ADatabase and that the databaseName is the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the `dbo.` owner designation:

```
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("? = spWCoTaskIdGen(?)");
statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
statement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
statement.executeQuery();
```

Also, and this is a longshot, are you sure you're in the correct database within the database server?

Comment: I have tried this and received the same error message.  That example has been added to the original question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using SQLServer 2012 Express.
I solved it starting the "SQL Server Browser" service.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing your Java code to use "exec" instead of "call"?
That is:

```
CallableStatement statement = connection
                    .prepareCall("{exec dbo.spWCoTaskIdGen(?)}");
```