# How do I execute a MS SQL Server stored procedure in java/jsp, returning table data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jsp, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am having difficulty executing a MS SQL Server stored procedure from Java/jsp.  I wish to return a table set of data; the last line of the stored procedure is a regular select statement from a table.

(From this point, executing a stored procedure is a cinch in `PHP`.)

I took a look at these sites for help:
[www.2netave.com](http://www.2netave.com/goodies/jdbc.htm)
[www.stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726935/unable-to-execute-stored-procedure-using-java-and-jdbc-on-sql-server)

I didn't realize there's a function just for stored procedures, as I was using `createStatement()` instead.

Now, please understand the stored procedure executes perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio and I have had no problems executing ad-hoc queries in jsp/java with `createStatement()`.

I created a simple stored procedure that takes no arguments, just to narrow down the problem:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test AS
BEGIN
PRINT 'HELLO WORLD'
END
```

Here is the code in my jsp page:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MySQLServer:1433/test", "user", "pass");
java.sql.CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_test}"); 
java.sql.ResultSet ResultSet = cs.execute();
```

The browser is telling me that the page cannot be displayed because an interal server error has occurred. I know this means there is an issue with the code above.

I tried this:

```
java.sql.ResultSet ResultSet = cs.executeQuery();
```

And this:

```
java.sql.CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{execute sp_test}");
```

And this:

```
java.sql.CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{exec sp_test}");
```

And nothing worked. Once I can get this working, then I can run an actual stored procedure that returns table data from a select statement. But I can't even get this dummy stored procedure to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

**Update:**

Checked the server logs (IIS) and my HTTP proxy, fiddler, and it doesn't report anything. However, the IIS is using tomcat as the servlet engine for jsp pages.  And tomcat log file reported the following:

```
An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to ResultSet
17: 
18:     java.sql.CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_test}");
19:     
20:     java.sql.ResultSet ResultSet = cs.execute();
21: 
22: //  java.sql.ResultSet ResultSet = state.executeQuery(SQL); 
23:
```

I tried changing the above to:

```
cs.execute();
```

And the log files reported:

```
- Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_test', database 'test', schema 'dbo'.
```

So, I have figured out I have to `GRANT EXECUTE` to the user. The other issue is returning table data from a stored procedure.

If I have a procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test2 AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TABLE
END
```

How do I manipulate the table data in jsp? Would `ResultSet` work or is that only for ad-hoc queries, as opposed to stored procedures, where one would use `createStatement()` to execute a query?

Thank you.

**Update2:**

Solution:

In order to manipulate table data, I had to use this:

```
java.sql.ResultSet RS = cs.executeQuery();
```

It failed on `execute()` and it failed on naming the `ResultSet` object "ResultSet". It never complained about this in the past with `createStatement()`. But for some reason, with stored procedures, it didn't like this naming convention.

Thank you.

Comment: *because an interal server error has occurred*. Please read the server logs to find the exception/stacktrace and include it in your question. It contains the answer.

Comment: Right, so I updated the question and found out that the user did not have proper permissions to execute.  So I changed the user's permissions (i.e. GRANT EXECUTE) and now that works.  There is a boolean error with the ResultSet.  This was just a dummy procedure; the real procedure has table data I want to process.  How can this be done?  Same as if I were to run an ad-hoc query?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Our server calls stored procs from Java like so - works on both SQL Server 2000 & 2008:

```
String SPsql = "EXEC <sp_name> ?,?";   // for stored proc taking 2 parameters
Connection con = SmartPoolFactory.getConnection();   // java.sql.Connection
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SPsql);
ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
ps.setQueryTimeout(<timeout value>);
ps.setString(1, <param1>);
ps.setString(2, <param2>);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I would also add to look at my method in the Update section of my question.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Brian Hughes: Where did you get SmartPoolFactory from?

Comment: If the SP is for **insert, update or delete** you should use `ResultSet rs = ps.executeUpdate();` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998700/sql-error-the-executequery-method-must-return-a-result-set)

Comment: @Brian Hughes Thanks for the Code Snippet. I was able to execute SP & fetch the ResultSet returned by SP.

Answer (score 6):

Thank to Brian for the code. I was trying to connect to the sql server with `{call spname(?,?)}` and I got errors, but when I change my code to `exec sp...` it works very well.

I post my code in hope this helps others with problems like mine:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement cs=null;
Connection conn=getJNDIConnection();

try {
    cs=conn.prepareStatement("exec sp_name ?,?,?,?,?,?,?");
    cs.setEscapeProcessing(true);
    cs.setQueryTimeout(90);

    cs.setString(1, "valueA");

    cs.setString(2, "valueB");

    cs.setString(3, "0418");

    //commented, because no need to register parameters out!, I got results from the resultset. 
    //cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    //cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);

    rs = cs.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<ObjectX> listaObjectX = new ArrayList<ObjectX>();
    while (rs.next()) {

        ObjectX to = new ObjectX();
        to.setFecha(rs.getString(1));
        to.setRefId(rs.getString(2));
        to.setRefNombre(rs.getString(3));
        to.setUrl(rs.getString(4));

        listaObjectX.add(to);

    }
    return listaObjectX;
     } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println("Error al ejecutar SQL"+ se.getMessage());
        se.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error al ejecutar SQL: " + se.getMessage());

    } finally {

        try {

            rs.close();
            cs.close();
          con.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Frequently we deal with other fellow java programmers work which create these Stored Procedure.
and we do not want to mess around with it.
but there is possibility you get the result set where these exec sample return 0 (almost Stored procedure call returning zero).

check this sample :

```
public void generateINOUT(String USER, int DPTID){

    try {


        conUrl = JdbcUrls + dbServers +";databaseName="+ dbSrcNames+";instance=MSSQLSERVER";

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,dbUserNames,dbPasswords);
        //stat = con.createStatement();
        con.setAutoCommit(false); 
        Statement st = con.createStatement(); 

        st.executeUpdate("DECLARE @RC int\n" +
                "DECLARE @pUserID nvarchar(50)\n" +
                "DECLARE @pDepartmentID int\n" +
                "DECLARE @pStartDateTime datetime\n" +
                "DECLARE @pEndDateTime datetime\n" +
                "EXECUTE [AccessManager].[dbo].[SP_GenerateInOutDetailReportSimple] \n" +
                ""+USER +
                "," +DPTID+
                ",'"+STARTDATE +
                "','"+ENDDATE+"'");

        ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();

        while (rs.next()){
              String userID = rs.getString("UserID");
              Timestamp timeIN = rs.getTimestamp("timeIN");
              Timestamp timeOUT = rs.getTimestamp ("timeOUT");
              int totTime = rs.getInt ("totalTime");
              int pivot = rs.getInt ("pivotvalue");

              timeINS = sdz.format(timeIN);
              userIN.add(timeINS);

              timeOUTS = sdz.format(timeOUT);
              userOUT.add(timeOUTS);

              System.out.println("User : "+userID+" |IN : "+timeIN+" |OUT : "+timeOUT+"| Total Time : "+totTime+" | PivotValue : "+pivot);
        }

        con.commit();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
        if (e.getCause() != null) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();}
    }  
}
```

I came to this solutions after few days trial and error, googling and get confused ;)
it execute below Stored Procedure :

```
USE [AccessManager]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_GenerateInOutDetailReportSimple]    
Script Date: 04/05/2013 15:54:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GenerateInOutDetailReportSimple]
(
@pUserID nvarchar(50),
@pDepartmentID int,
@pStartDateTime datetime,
@pEndDateTime datetime
)
AS


Declare @ErrorCode int
Select @ErrorCode = @@Error

Declare @TransactionCountOnEntry int
If @ErrorCode = 0
Begin
    Select @TransactionCountOnEntry = @@TranCount
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
End


If @ErrorCode = 0
Begin       

    -- Create table variable instead of SQL temp table because report wont pick up the temp table
    DECLARE @tempInOutDetailReport TABLE
    (
        UserID nvarchar(50),
        LogDate datetime,   
        LogDay varchar(20), 
        TimeIN datetime,
        TimeOUT datetime,
        TotalTime int,
        RemarkTimeIn nvarchar(100),
        RemarkTimeOut nvarchar(100),
        TerminalIPTimeIn varchar(50),
        TerminalIPTimeOut varchar(50),
        TerminalSNTimeIn nvarchar(50),
        TerminalSNTimeOut nvarchar(50),
        PivotValue int
    )           

    -- Declare variables for the while loop
    Declare @LogUserID nvarchar(50)
    Declare @LogEventID nvarchar(50)
    Declare @LogTerminalSN nvarchar(50)
    Declare @LogTerminalIP nvarchar(50)
    Declare @LogRemark nvarchar(50)
    Declare @LogTimestamp datetime  
    Declare @LogDay nvarchar(20)

    -- Filter off userID, departmentID, StartDate and EndDate if specified, only process the remaining logs
    -- Note: order by user then timestamp
    Declare LogCursor Cursor For 
    Select distinct access_event_logs.USERID, access_event_logs.EVENTID, 
        access_event_logs.TERMINALSN, access_event_logs.TERMINALIP,
        access_event_logs.REMARKS, access_event_logs.LOCALTIMESTAMP, Datename(dw,access_event_logs.LOCALTIMESTAMP) AS WkDay
    From access_event_logs
        Left Join access_user on access_user.User_ID = access_event_logs.USERID
        Left Join access_user_dept on access_user.User_ID = access_user_dept.User_ID
    Where ((Dept_ID = @pDepartmentID) OR (@pDepartmentID IS NULL))
        And ((access_event_logs.USERID LIKE '%' + @pUserID + '%') OR (@pUserID IS NULL)) 
        And ((access_event_logs.LOCALTIMESTAMP >= @pStartDateTime ) OR (@pStartDateTime IS NULL)) 
        And ((access_event_logs.LOCALTIMESTAMP < DATEADD(day, 1, @pEndDateTime) ) OR (@pEndDateTime IS NULL)) 
        And (access_event_logs.USERID != 'UNKNOWN USER') -- Ignore UNKNOWN USER
    Order by access_event_logs.USERID, access_event_logs.LOCALTIMESTAMP

    Open LogCursor

    Fetch Next 
    From LogCursor
    Into @LogUserID, @LogEventID, @LogTerminalSN, @LogTerminalIP, @LogRemark, @LogTimestamp, @LogDay

    -- Temp storage for IN event details
    Declare @InEventUserID nvarchar(50)
    Declare @InEventDay nvarchar(20)
    Declare @InEventTimestamp datetime
    Declare @InEventRemark nvarchar(100)
    Declare @InEventTerminalIP nvarchar(50)
    Declare @InEventTerminalSN nvarchar(50)

    -- Temp storage for OUT event details
    Declare @OutEventUserID nvarchar(50)        
    Declare @OutEventTimestamp datetime
    Declare @OutEventRemark nvarchar(100)
    Declare @OutEventTerminalIP nvarchar(50)
    Declare @OutEventTerminalSN nvarchar(50)

    Declare @CurrentUser varchar(50) -- used to indicate when we change user group
    Declare @CurrentDay varchar(50) -- used to indicate when we change day
    Declare @FirstEvent int -- indicate the first event we received     
    Declare @ReceiveInEvent int -- indicate we have received an IN event
    Declare @PivotValue int -- everytime we change user or day - we reset it (reporting purpose), if same user..keep increment its value
    Declare @CurrTrigger varchar(50) -- used to keep track of the event of the current event log trigger it is handling 
    Declare @CurrTotalHours int -- used to keep track of total hours of the day of the user

    Declare @FirstInEvent datetime
    Declare @FirstInRemark nvarchar(100)
    Declare @FirstInTerminalIP nvarchar(50)
    Declare @FirstInTerminalSN nvarchar(50)
    Declare @FirstRecord int -- indicate another day of same user

    Set @PivotValue = 0 -- initialised
    Set @CurrentUser = '' -- initialised
    Set @FirstEvent = 1 -- initialised
    Set @ReceiveInEvent = 0 -- initialised  
    Set @CurrTrigger = '' -- Initialised    
    Set @CurrTotalHours = 0 -- initialised
    Set @FirstRecord = 1 -- initialised
    Set @CurrentDay = '' -- initialised

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        -- use to track current log trigger
        Set @CurrTrigger =LOWER(@LogEventID)

        If (@CurrentUser != '' And @CurrentUser != @LogUserID) -- new batch of user
        Begin
            If @ReceiveInEvent = 1  -- previous IN event is not cleared (no OUT is found)
            Begin
                -- Check day
                If (@CurrentDay != @InEventDay) -- change to another day                    
                    Set @PivotValue = 0 -- Reset                        

                Else -- same day
                    Set @PivotValue = @PivotValue + 1 -- increment
                Set @CurrentDay = @InEventDay -- update the day

                -- invalid row (only has IN event)
                Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeIN, RemarkTimeIn, TerminalIPTimeIn, 
                    TerminalSNTimeIn, PivotValue, LogDate )
                values( @InEventUserID, @InEventDay, @InEventTimestamp, @InEventRemark, @InEventTerminalIP, 
                    @InEventTerminalSN, @PivotValue, DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InEventTimestamp)))                                                         
            End                 

            Set @FirstEvent = 1 -- Reset flag (we are having a new user group)
            Set @ReceiveInEvent = 0 -- Reset
            Set @PivotValue = 0 -- Reset
            --Set @CurrentDay = '' -- Reset
        End

        If LOWER(@LogEventID) = 'in' -- IN event
        Begin           
            If @ReceiveInEvent = 1  -- previous IN event is not cleared (no OUT is found)
            Begin
                -- Check day
                If (@CurrentDay != @InEventDay) -- change to another day
                Begin
                    Set @PivotValue = 0 -- Reset

                    --Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeIN, TimeOUT, TotalTime, RemarkTimeIn,
                    --  RemarkTimeOut, TerminalIPTimeIn, TerminalIPTimeOut, TerminalSNTimeIn, TerminalSNTimeOut, PivotValue,
                    --  LogDate)
                    --values( @LogUserID, @CurrentDay, @FirstInEvent, @LogTimestamp,  @CurrTotalHours,
                    --  @FirstInRemark, @LogRemark, @FirstInTerminalIP, @LogTerminalIP, @FirstInTerminalSN, @LogTerminalSN, @PivotValue,
                    --  DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InEventTimestamp)))  
                End
                Else
                    Set @PivotValue = @PivotValue + 1 -- increment
                Set @CurrentDay = @InEventDay -- update the day


                -- invalid row (only has IN event)
                Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeIN, RemarkTimeIn, TerminalIPTimeIn, 
                    TerminalSNTimeIn, PivotValue, LogDate )
                values( @InEventUserID, @InEventDay, @InEventTimestamp, @InEventRemark, @InEventTerminalIP, 
                    @InEventTerminalSN, @PivotValue, DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InEventTimestamp)))                     
            End         

            If((@CurrentDay != @LogDay And @CurrentDay != '') Or (@CurrentUser != @LogUserID And @CurrentUser != '') )
            Begin

                    Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeIN, TimeOUT, TotalTime, RemarkTimeIn,
                        RemarkTimeOut, TerminalIPTimeIn, TerminalIPTimeOut, TerminalSNTimeIn, TerminalSNTimeOut, PivotValue,
                        LogDate)
                    values( @CurrentUser, @CurrentDay, @FirstInEvent, @OutEventTimestamp, @CurrTotalHours,
                        @FirstInRemark, @OutEventRemark, @FirstInTerminalIP, @OutEventTerminalIP, @FirstInTerminalSN, @LogTerminalSN, @PivotValue,
                        DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InEventTimestamp)))      

                Set @FirstRecord = 1
            End
            -- Save it
            Set @InEventUserID = @LogUserID                         
            Set @InEventDay = @LogDay
            Set @InEventTimestamp = @LogTimeStamp
            Set @InEventRemark = @LogRemark
            Set @InEventTerminalIP = @LogTerminalIP
            Set @InEventTerminalSN = @LogTerminalSN

            If (@FirstRecord = 1) -- save for first in event record of the day
            Begin
                Set @FirstInEvent = @LogTimestamp
                Set @FirstInRemark = @LogRemark
                Set @FirstInTerminalIP = @LogTerminalIP
                Set @FirstInTerminalSN = @LogTerminalSN
                Set @CurrTotalHours = 0 --initialise total hours for another day
            End

            Set @FirstRecord = 0 -- no more first record of the day
            Set @ReceiveInEvent = 1 -- indicate we have received an "IN" event
            Set @FirstEvent = 0  -- no more "first" event
        End
        Else If LOWER(@LogEventID) = 'out' -- OUT event
        Begin
            If @FirstEvent = 1 -- the first OUT record when change users 
            Begin
                -- Check day
                If (@CurrentDay != @LogDay) -- change to another day
                    Set @PivotValue = 0 -- Reset
                Else
                    Set @PivotValue = @PivotValue + 1 -- increment
                Set @CurrentDay = @LogDay -- update the day

                -- Only an OUT event (no IN event) - invalid record but we show it anyway
                Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeOUT, RemarkTimeOut, TerminalIPTimeOut, TerminalSNTimeOut,
                    PivotValue, LogDate )
                values( @LogUserID, @LogDay, @LogTimestamp, @LogRemark, @LogTerminalIP, @LogTerminalSN, @PivotValue,
                    DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @LogTimestamp)))                                              

                Set @FirstEvent = 0 -- not "first" anymore
            End
            Else -- Not first event
            Begin       

                If @ReceiveInEvent = 1 -- if there are IN event previously
                Begin           
                    -- Check day
                    If (@CurrentDay != @InEventDay) -- change to another day                        
                        Set @PivotValue = 0 -- Reset                        
                    Else
                        Set @PivotValue = @PivotValue + 1 -- increment
                    Set @CurrentDay = @InEventDay -- update the day     
                    Set @CurrTotalHours = @CurrTotalHours +  DATEDIFF(second,@InEventTimestamp, @LogTimeStamp) -- update total time             

                    Set @OutEventRemark = @LogRemark
                    Set @OutEventTerminalIP = @LogTerminalIP
                    Set @OutEventTerminalSN = @LogTerminalSN
                    Set @OutEventTimestamp = @LogTimestamp          
                    -- valid row
                    --Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeIN, TimeOUT, TotalTime, RemarkTimeIn,
                    --  RemarkTimeOut, TerminalIPTimeIn, TerminalIPTimeOut, TerminalSNTimeIn, TerminalSNTimeOut, PivotValue,
                    --  LogDate)
                    --values( @LogUserID, @InEventDay, @InEventTimestamp, @LogTimestamp,  Datediff(second, @InEventTimestamp, @LogTimeStamp),
                    --  @InEventRemark, @LogRemark, @InEventTerminalIP, @LogTerminalIP, @InEventTerminalSN, @LogTerminalSN, @PivotValue,
                    --  DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InEventTimestamp)))                      

                    Set @ReceiveInEvent = 0 -- Reset
                End
                Else -- no IN event previously
                Begin
                    -- Check day
                    If (@CurrentDay != @LogDay) -- change to another day
                        Set @PivotValue = 0 -- Reset
                    Else
                        Set @PivotValue = @PivotValue + 1 -- increment
                    Set @CurrentDay = @LogDay -- update the day                         

                    -- invalid row (only has OUT event)
                    Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeOUT, RemarkTimeOut, TerminalIPTimeOut, TerminalSNTimeOut,
                        PivotValue, LogDate )
                    values( @LogUserID, @LogDay, @LogTimestamp, @LogRemark, @LogTerminalIP, @LogTerminalSN, @PivotValue,
                        DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @LogTimestamp)) )             
                End             
            End         
        End

        Set @CurrentUser = @LogUserID -- update user        

        Fetch Next 
        From LogCursor
        Into @LogUserID, @LogEventID, @LogTerminalSN, @LogTerminalIP, @LogRemark, @LogTimestamp, @LogDay
    End 

    -- Need to handle the last log if its IN log as it will not be processed by the while loop
    if @CurrTrigger='in'
    Begin 
    -- Check day
            If (@CurrentDay != @InEventDay) -- change to another day
                Set @PivotValue = 0 -- Reset
            Else -- same day
                Set @PivotValue = @PivotValue + 1 -- increment
            Set @CurrentDay = @InEventDay -- update the day

            -- invalid row (only has IN event)
            Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeIN, RemarkTimeIn, TerminalIPTimeIn, 
                TerminalSNTimeIn, PivotValue, LogDate )
            values( @InEventUserID, @InEventDay, @InEventTimestamp, @InEventRemark, @InEventTerminalIP, 
                    @InEventTerminalSN, @PivotValue, DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InEventTimestamp)))     
    End
    else if @CurrTrigger = 'out'
    Begin
        Insert into @tempInOutDetailReport( UserID, LogDay, TimeIN, TimeOUT, TotalTime, RemarkTimeIn,
        RemarkTimeOut, TerminalIPTimeIn, TerminalIPTimeOut, TerminalSNTimeIn, TerminalSNTimeOut, PivotValue,
        LogDate)
        values( @LogUserID, @CurrentDay, @FirstInEvent, @LogTimestamp,  @CurrTotalHours,
        @FirstInRemark, @LogRemark, @FirstInTerminalIP, @LogTerminalIP, @FirstInTerminalSN, @LogTerminalSN, @PivotValue,
        DATEADD(HOUR, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @InEventTimestamp)))  
    End

    Close LogCursor
    Deallocate LogCursor

    Select * 
    From @tempInOutDetailReport tempTable
        Left Join access_user on access_user.User_ID = tempTable.UserID
    Order By tempTable.UserID, LogDate


End



If @@TranCount > @TransactionCountOnEntry
Begin
     If @ErrorCode = 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
     Else
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
End

return @ErrorCode
```

you will get the "java SQL Code" by right click on stored procedure in your database.
something like this :

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @pUserID nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @pDepartmentID int
DECLARE @pStartDateTime datetime
DECLARE @pEndDateTime datetime

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [AccessManager].[dbo].[SP_GenerateInOutDetailReportSimple] 
@pUserID,@pDepartmentID,@pStartDateTime,@pEndDateTime
GO
```

check the query String I've done, that is your homework ;)
so sorry answering this long,
this is my first answer since I register few weeks ago to get answer.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, sp_test will not be returning anything but an integer (all SQL Server stored procs just return an integer) and no result sets on the wire (since no SELECT statements).  To get the output of the PRINT statements, you normally use the InfoMessage event on the connection (not the command) in ADO.NET.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm using JSP, however.  Nonetheless, the main point is returning table data and manipulating it in JSP.  Thanks again for your input.