# SQL Error: The executeQuery method must return a result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

while trying to execute the below query in SQL server I am getting an error SQL Error: The executeQuery method must return a result set.

```
with cte 
AS
(
    SELECT GUID,seq original_seq_no, ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER ( PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY seq) AS new_seq_no
    FROM CHK_SEQ
)

update  CHK_SEQ
set     CHK_SEQ.seq = r.new_seq_no
from    cte r
where CHK_SEQ.seq = r.original_seq_no AND CHK_SEQ.GUID= r.GUID;
```

can any one please help me with this.

Comment: I assume you do this from application code, and you must use something like `executeNonQuery()` instead of `executeQuery()` (depending on language of course).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am writing this statement to update the table as some bad data has been entered through UI. I am not doing it through application code.

Answer (score 13):

> executeQuery method must return a result set

Your query does not return a result set. Is an UPDATE. Use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead, [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) for Java

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am writing this query to update the table as some bad data has been entered through UI. I am not doing it through application code.

Comment: That is a Java error, so is a client error. The engine does not throw Java errors.

Comment: @user2810293 Which program (UI) are you using for DB management?

Comment: I am running the script directly in SQL developer, not through any java code.Error at Command Line:1 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: The executeQuery method must return a result set

Comment: Run the script from [SQL Server Management Studio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx). Have SQL Developer run the statements as a non-query (ask an appropiate question, labeled with Oracle toolset, not SQL server). Add a dummy result set. Pick your poison. Learn to help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To return data from a SELECT Statement

```
String sql_select = "Select name from people";

Statement st_1 = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs_1 = st_1.executeQuery((sql_select));
```

To just run an UPDATE statement

```
String sql_update = "Update people set name = 'Natalie' 
Statement st_2 = connection.createStatement();
st_2.executeUpdate(sql_update);
```