# How to perform sql procedure by java using regexp as parameter in procedure?

Tags: java, sql-server, regex, stored-procedures, jdbc

Fields validation parameter has  `^[A-Za-z\-.']*$` value by default in my sql database.

I have a stored procedure which is able to change some parameter.

I try to update this parameter with `^[A-Za-z0-9\-.']*$`.

I try to perform the procedure with `CallableStatement`. Please see below:

```
String newRegexValue = "^[A-Za-z0-9\-.']*$";
String parameterName = "ValidationParameter";
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("exec UpdateProcedure '"+parameterName  +"', '"+ newRegexValue +"' ");
callableStatement .execute();
```

But I got SQLServerException:

> Incorrect syntax near `^`

I tried to add a backslash before `^` but error remains.

I suppose the main problem is in screening `newRegexValue`.

Comment: Could you show the `T-SQL` statements in your store procedure?

Comment: @   Docteur, backslashes surraunds  regexp are not helps

@ gotqn, sorry,  cannot show

Comment: You might have a range declared, from a literal backslash and a literal `.`? I think you need to check escaping in the regex. Try putting unescaped hyphen at the end of the character class.

Comment: @stribizhev,  tried  but not helps

Comment: What about the apostrophe in the pattern? Can you pass it like this? It might need escaping: `\'`. This symbol is also used as value delimiter in the SQL command.

Comment: Please check this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113674/how-do-i-execute-a-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-java-jsp-returning-table-d. I think you can have problems with passing parameters to the stored procedure.

Comment: @stribizhev, I tried to delete \' in my value and use value as "'^[A-Za-z0-9-.'' ]*$'"  - paramter was updated successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the single quotation mark (apostrophe), as it is also used in the SQL command. You either need to escape it (`\'`), or - if it is used in some XML - use the `&apos;` entity.

If you do not want to allow apostrophes in the matches, just remove it from the regex.

Comment: I tried to remove \' and updated my value with "'^[A-Za-z0-9-. '' ]*$'"  - paramter was succesfully updated!

Comment: Thanks all for answers, espessually stribizhev!

Comment: I replaced \' with &apos; - " Incorrect syntax near ^" error in console.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape your slash. Try this:

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9\\-.']*$"
```

Comment: tried but  got SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ^

Comment: Wait.. Have you tried to replace the `,` with a space between the `parameterName` and the `value`? [See here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx) @user2837153

Comment: (Or with an `=` sign)

Comment: nope , my procedure has nex view dbo.UpdateProcedure(@parameterName  varchar(50), @Value varchar(150))