# ResultSet is empty, event though the sql query is ok

Tags: java, sql-server, resultset

I  have the following Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Uspinformation3 (@TypeNr    VARCHAR(50), 
                                 @Process   VARCHAR(50), 
                                 @StartDate VARCHAR(50), 
                                 @EndDate   VARCHAR(50)) 
AS 
  BEGIN try 
      SET dateformat dmy; 

      SELECT Count(rownr) 
      FROM   diff_ct 
      WHERE  type_number = @TypeNr 
             AND process = @Process 
             AND full_time_stamp BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
  END try
```

If I execute the Procedure from SQL Server, it gives me the wanted answer

```
EXEC uspInformation3 1137328582, 427, 
                     {ts '2015-05-24 12:00:00'}, {ts  ' 2015-05-24 16:00:00 '}
```

But, when I try to do it from Java, the Result Set is always empty. Where am I doing a mistake? I guess that it has something to do with the data types that I am using?

```
 try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_Connection);

              String partno = pn.getText();
              String processname = procname.getText();
            // String StartTime =  DataStart.getText();  
      String StartTime = "{ts " +"'"+ DataStart.getText() +"'}";


            String EndTime = "{ts " +"'"+ DataFinal.getText()+"'}";


      System.out.println(StartTime);


            Statement state = conn.createStatement();
     CallableStatement cs = null;


     cs = conn.prepareCall("{call uspInformation3(?,?,?,?)}");
        cs.setString(1, partno);
        cs.setString(2, processname);
        cs.setString(3, StartTime);
        cs.setString(4, EndTime);
        cs.executeQuery();

       ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();

       System.out.println(rs);
        if(rs.next()) {

               String totalct = rs.getString(1);
               System.out.println(totalct);
           totalctno.setText(totalct);                      

          }
```

Comment: what is the type of Full_Time_Stamp column? Why are you using StartDate & EndDate as varchar rather than Date/Timestamp?

Comment: The Full_Time_Stamp is a datetime. And I am using them as varchar, because from java, I couldn't send them as datetime values.

Comment: SQL Server's datetime maps to java.sql.Timestamp. Look here for possible mappings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I was able to sove it, after I made it a timestamp

Comment: You should also learn to indent your code properly. Makes reading your code a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try send the parameter as string?  Or change the parameter type to `datetime`

Also there was extra spaces there on second date.

```
EXEC uspInformation3 1137328582, 427, 
                     '2015-05-24 12:00:00', '2015-05-24 16:00:00';
```

Comment: Yes. If I use it as strings, it gives me the following error :The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. Because Full_Time_Stamp has a datetime type.

Comment: maybe try this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113674/how-do-i-execute-a-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-java-jsp-returning-table-d Here use prepareStatement instead of prepare call

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it, after I changed the parameters to timestamps.