# how to execute a storedprocedure from preparestatement

Tags: android, sql-server, stored-procedures

how do i execute my stored procedure.
the procedure works when i execute it directly from the sql but it doesn't work when i do it from my tablet

```
String itemshelf = DBshelf;// edittext for putting in values on set
String itemcard = DBcard;// edittext for putting in values on where
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("EXEC [dbo].[spUpd_Location]");
                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpd_Location]
   @itemshelf nvarchar(1000)=NULL
 , @itemcard nvarchar(1000)=NULL
 AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
UPDATE PS
SET [ShelfNumber]=@itemshelf
FROM [file].[ItemPart] PS
JOIN [file].[Item] P ON P.[id] = PS.[id]
where [ItemNumber]=@itemcard
```

Comment: What are the errors? executeUpdate looks wrong as thats not a direct update

Comment: i don't get any errors but it doesn't change the values in the database

Comment: @itemcard is NULL so the equality test is false for all rows, call it with the 2 params? (If you want equality with null use IS NULL)

Comment: after i removed null i got expects parameter '@itemshelf', which was not supplied. on my prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure is expecting two arguments which you will need to supply to the prepared statement.  Your SQL needs placeholders for the arguments and the arguments need to be set on the `PreparedStatement` object.  Your code would then look something like:

```
String itemshelf = DBshelf;// edittext for putting in values on set
String itemcard = DBcard;// edittext for putting in values on where
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("EXEC [dbo].[spUpd_Location] ?, ?;");
preparedStatement.setString(1, itemshelf);
preparedStatement.setString(2, itemcard);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: i getting Invalid parameter index 1

Comment: The SQL statement was missing an open bracket on the stored procedure name (edited to fix) which may be the problem.

Comment: Here's a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113674/how-do-i-execute-a-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-java-jsp-returning-table-d) that may help.

Also, the stored procedure doesn't appear to return anything, so the `executeUpdate` should probably be just `execute`.